# Por que no completa la etiqueta con la palabra de Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap

Tengo Bootstrap por CDN, pero no me da las sugerencias para completar la etiqueta en mi Proyecto Angular. ¿Alguno sabe por qué? Por ejemplo, quiero hacer un **text-center** o **bg-primary**, pero no me da la sugerencia para terminar la etiqueta automaticamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si no me equivoco, esto no funcionaría con los cdn. Para que funcione tendrías que tener descargado el bootstrap en tu proyecto y ya reconocerá las clases, mira esta [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/)

Comment: Muchas gracias, pense que se podia!

Comment: Sea local o en CDN, la mejor forma de que el VS Code te autocomplete las clases de Boostrap es con un plugin, según la versión que uses, por ejemplo, esta para la versión 5: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AnbuselvanRocky.bootstrap5-vscode